# I am trying to work out Xpath or CSS for an Add button

Tags: python, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am having trouble identifying the Add button on our website which I am in the process of automating.  Python, Webdriver.
Selenium IDE gives the following Xpath:

```
adminAdd_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button'])[33]")
adminAdd_button.click()
```

I get the following error when i try this Xpath in my python, webdriver code.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The xpath expression '//button[@type='button'])[33]' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement
```

I have also tried the following Xpath with no luck:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[. = 'Add']")
```

Does anyone know what Xpath I can use for this please?  Or CSS as CSS is quicker to execute than Xpath.  Thanks.

HTML source is as follows (The Add is at the bottom of the source).  There are so many div tags:

```
<html style="overflow: hidden;">
<head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
<iframe id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; border: 0;" tabindex="-1" src="javascript:''">
<noscript> <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif;"> Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled in order for this application to display correctly.</div> </noscript>
<script src="spinner.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="ClearCore/ClearCore.nocache.js" type="text/javascript">
<script defer="defer">
<iframe id="ClearCore" src="javascript:''" style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: medium none;" tabindex="-1">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20cm; width: 10cm; height: 10cm; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 1px; top: 1px; right: 1px; bottom: 1px;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanel" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 30px;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 16384px;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GAT4PNUK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner">
</div>
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GAT4PNUK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner">
</div>
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GAT4PNUK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner">
</div>
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GAT4PNUK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner">
</div>
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GAT4PNUK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner">
</div>
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GAT4PNUK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner">
<div class="gwt-HTML">Operations</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GAT4PNUK gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab-selected" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner">
<div class="gwt-HTML">Administration</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 30px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelContentContainer" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: -100%; top: 0%; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; display: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; display: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; display: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; display: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 100%; top: 0%; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelContent" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 35px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 35px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div class="gwt-SplitLayoutPanel" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 160px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 160px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 8px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 168px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 24px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 24px; right: 0px; height: 24px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 48px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanel" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 30px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 30px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelContentContainer" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0%; top: 0%; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelContent" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;" aria-hidden="false">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 35px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 35px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div class="gwt-SplitLayoutPanel" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 160px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 160px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 8px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 168px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="right: 0px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 24px;">
<div class="workspacetoolbar" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 5px;">
<span class="gwt-InlineLabel" style="font-weight: bold; color: black; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 20px;">Projects</span>
<div class="GAT4PNUMP">
<button class="gwt-Button" type="button">
<div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 2px;">
<div id="prueba" class="gwt-HTML" style="margin-left: 15px;">Add...</div>
</button>
<button class="gwt-Button" type="button" disabled="">
<button class="gwt-Button workspacebuttontext75" type="button" title="Delete" disabled="">Delete ▼</button>
<div class="GAT4PNUMP">
```

Comment: if you have the *class* why not just do: `find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='gwt-Button']")`?

Comment: but ensure you're *ACTUALLY* switched to iframe.

Comment: Using indexes in selectors is bad practice, imho. If you provide more of needed div contents I could try to build a valid css-selector for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<div>` doesn't have exactly "Add" text in it, try using `starts-with()` instead :

```
//div[starts-with(., 'Add')]
```

The button isn't quite well formed -it doesn't have corresponding closing tag, so it's hard to be sure how browser would interprets it. Assuming that the `div` with text `Add...` interpreted as *child* of the button, this should also work :

```
//button[starts-with(., 'Add')]
```

Comment: Thanks - I can find the button in FirePath using your Xpath.  When i run my code it does not find it.  I have just spoken with the developer and she says the add button is not unique.  There are other add buttons on the page.  I need to find the parent class and then the child which has the Add button.  The button is in the Administration class e.g. <div class="gwt-HTML">Administration</div>  I have pasted the full html in my question above

Comment: The dev says she can build a JQuery to select the button by CSS.  Can i use JQuery in Selenium Webdriver?  I could use her JQuey then.

Comment: @RiazLadhani Assuming that she uses CSS selector with JQuery to select the button, then you can utilize the same selector with Selenium. See : http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors

Comment: I have managed to find the button now by using the following Xpath: driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[8]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/button[1]")  It's not the best Xpath if the structure changes.  I will use it for now until i can find a better Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are getting `InvalidSelectorException` exception because of the extra closing parenthesis in the XPath expression:

```
//button[@type='button'])[33]
                    HERE^
```

The `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[. = 'Add']")` approach is not working since you are asking the `div` element's text to be exactly equal to `Add` which is not true, the text is `Add...`:

```
//div[. = 'Add...']
```

And, according to the posted HTML code, the desired `div` element is not inside an `iframe` and, hence, no switching necessary.

Another important thing to note: are you really sure this `div` element is clickable? It could be that the parent `button` element is something you want to click:

```
//button[div[. = 'Add...']]
```